# Momentjs how to set global locale

Tags: reactjs, react-native, momentjs

How can i add global locale to date

i have this code and it appear only english language
i would like to translate month globally for any language in device

```
{moment.unix(Number(item.orderdate)).format("DD.MMMM.YYYY")}
```

dont know what i should write more
This question body does not meet our quality standards. Please make sure that it completely describes your problem - including what you have already tried - and is written using proper grammar.

Answer (score 1):

you need to laad locale first see [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/loading-into-nodejs/), then set locale global see [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/).

```js
//in App.js file
import moment from 'moment';
//import locale file(s)
import 'moment/locale/fr';
moment.locale('fr');


//use it in any file like that
import moment from 'moment';
moment(1316116057189).fromNow(); // il y a 6 ans
```